# Refer existing VPC for Aurora cluster creation in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

How do I refer an already existing VPC & its subnet ids while creating a DB Subnet group for an Aurora resource using the Serverless framework ?

```
Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "Aurora Subnet Group"
        SubnetIds:
          - Ref: AuroraSubnetA
          - Ref: AuroraSubnetB
```

Most of the documentation out there only seem to point to a '**vpc**' section for lambdas. I am unable to figure how to use this section for a database resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to pass the Subnet IDs in as parameters and reference those.